# linux shred does not remove traces of filename even after truncate/removal?

Tags: linux, security, secure-erase, wipe

I'm testing the coreutils `/usr/bin/shred` command.

It leaves traces of a file's name even though I told shred to "truncate" (remove) the file. I was assuming that shred would remove all the metadata of the file's name. Is this expected behavior?

You won't be able to copy/paste this but it gives you an idea of what I'm doing:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=fs bs=1M count=300
hexdump -C fs   # verify it's empty
mkfs.ext4 fs
mkdir m
sudo mount fs m
sudo chown -R $USER m
cd m
echo secretkey > passwords.txt
cd ..
sudo umount m
grep secretkey fs   # <== shows up as expected
grep passwords.txt fs
hexdump -C fs | grep sec
hexdump -C fs | grep pass
sudo mount fs m
cd m
/usr/bin/shred -vuz -n 1 passwords.txt
cd ..
sudo umount m
grep secretkey fs   # <== does not show up, this is good
grep passwords.txt fs   # <== PROBLEM: filename still shows
hexdump -C fs | grep sec
hexdump -C fs | grep pass
```

The 'mount' command for this fs gives:

```
type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
```

Help?

Answer (score 0):

`man shred` says:

```
NAME
       shred - overwrite a file to hide its contents, and optionally delete it

DESCRIPTION
       Overwrite the specified FILE(s) repeatedly, in order to make it harder for
       even very expensive hardware probing to recover the data.
```

This only mentions the file contents/data, and never implies also hiding the file name, which would be a different problem (possible hard/soft links, etc...). Did you try to rename the file before shredding it?

Comment: Smart idea about renaming. Just tried and it didn't help. I see the names of both the previous and new file name in the file system. In fact I see multiple copies of the file's name (ext4 superblock backups?). I might change the OP to specifically ask for a method in linux to securely remove a file's name from the file system.